# so-long not detecting a long line in compilation output

Tags: init-file, quote

I am trying to use `so-long` to improve the performance of `compilation-mode` when the compiler output contains very long lines (1000s of characters).

When the compilation runs and I `M-x so-long-minor-mode`, then the performance is immediately fine - `so-long` successfully puts the minor modes to sleep, and whichever is the culprit (not relevant to this question) goes away.

I have tried automating this in my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` with these customizations:

```
(custom-set-variables
 .
 .
 .
 '(global-so-long-mode t)
 '(so-long-action 'so-long-minor-mode)
 ; '(so-long-predicate 'so-long-detected-long-line-p) 
 '(so-long-target-modes
   '(prog-mode css-mode sgml-mode nxml-mode fundamental-mode compilation-mode comint-mode))
 '(so-long-threshold 500)
 .
 .
 .
```

Nothing happens. When I run a compilation, it happily spits out long lines, but `so-long-minor-mode` does not activate. Changing `so-long-predicate` does not help.

I cannot simply add `so-long-minor-mode` to the `auto-mode-alist`  of `compilation-mode` as in 99% of the cases (i.e. no long lines) I actually do want those minor modes.

What do I need to do to enable `so-long-minor-mode` in compilations with very long lines? Or am I misunderstanding how `so-long` is supposed to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the final paragraph of the Introduction in the documentation:

> Note also that the mitigations are automatically triggered when visiting a
> file.  The library does not automatically detect if long lines are inserted
> into an existing buffer (although the `so-long' command can be invoked
> manually in such situations).

You could use this:

```
(add-hook 'compilation-mode-hook 'so-long-minor-mode)
```

But if you want to apply the minor mode *only* when long lines are generated, my best suggestion is to make use of `compilation-filter-hook`:

```
compilation-filter-hook is a variable defined in `compile.el.gz'.

Its value is (colorize-compilation-output)

Hook run after `compilation-filter' has inserted a string into the buffer.
It is called with the variable `compilation-filter-start' bound
to the position of the start of the inserted text, and point at
its end.

If Emacs lacks asynchronous process support, this hook is run
after `call-process' inserts the grep output into the buffer.

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.
  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 24.1.
```

E.g.:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'compile
  (require 'so-long))

(add-hook 'compilation-mode-hook 'my-so-long-compilation-mode)

(defun my-so-long-compilation-mode ()
  "Add `my-so-long-compilation-filter' to local `compilation-filter-hook'."
  (add-hook 'compilation-filter-hook
            'my-so-long-compilation-filter nil :local))

(defun my-so-long-compilation-filter ()
  "Maybe call `so-long-minor-mode' during `compilation-filter-hook'."
  (let ((start (save-excursion (goto-char compilation-filter-start)
                               (line-beginning-position))))
    (when (> (- (point) start) so-long-threshold)
      (save-restriction
        (narrow-to-region start (point))
        (when (let (so-long-max-lines so-long-skip-leading-comments)
                (funcall so-long-predicate))
          (so-long-minor-mode 1)
          (remove-hook 'compilation-filter-hook
                       'my-so-long-compilation-filter :local))))))
```

Comment: If you're testing that code with `lgrep` or `rgrep`, remember that there's a pretty long line right at the start of the output which is mostly hidden behind the abbreviated `[…]` display.

Comment: I gave it a short whirl, but it did not activate the mode for me (I even quickly commented out the `when` exps to enforce it). Still, a very cool idea, thanks for the effort, I'm sure I will get it running with some debugging later (will post if I find the reason, maybe it's something else in my quite large init.el file ;) )!

Comment: Try it with `emacs -Q` -- works fine for me in Emacs 27, 28, 29, although I note that my earlier comment about lgrep/rgrep doesn't apply in 27 and earlier, as that long line isn't subject to the compilation filter (in 28+ the so-long-predicate sees the whole buffer, though).  In any case, set `so-long-threshold` to a very small value and I'd expect you to be able to trigger it?

Comment: A simple `M-x compile` test also works for me.  If you can't figure out what's going wrong and you can give me a recipe for reproducing a failure starting from `emacs -Q`, I don't mind taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

You quoted all of the code that you added to your init file, so of course the code was never evaluated.

Comment: I *suspect* it was an excerpt from the `(custom-set-variables` form -- but it's not clear.

Comment: That is a possibility, now that you mention it.

Comment: Confirmed by the edit to the question.